# Fitting subview to it's parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, subview

I have a problematic UIView called as MyListViewController. It is at the first tab in my application.

I am adding a subview in the viewDidLoad section( there are some constraints defined on the subview ). **When I run the application the subview doesn't fit to it's root view well**. However, if I navigate to an another tab and then re-click to the first tab, the application fits the subview properly.

Also I can't use [self.detailView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]; because it causes heaps of constraint conflicts.

Anyway, I wrote my custom method, patchSubViewPadding, in order to fit the subView to it's rootView which is defined as detailView. **As I stated above if I navigate to one of the other tabs and then navigate to the the first tab the application shows up the subview properly**.

```
@interface MyListViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomViewController *customViewController;

@end

@implementation MyListViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    CustomViewController *viewController = (CustomViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customView"];
    self.customViewController = viewController;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        [self.detailView addSubview:self.customViewController.view];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [CommonUtilities patchSubViewPadding:self.detailView subView:self.customViewController.view padding:0];
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [CommonUtilities patchSubViewPadding:self.detailView subView:self.customViewController.view padding:0];
}

@end
```

And this is my custom method:

```
+(CGRect)patchSubViewPadding:(UIView *)superView subView:(UIView *)subView padding:(float)padding
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if (padding == 0)
            padding = -4.0f;

        CGRect frame = superView.bounds;

        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width - padding;
        subView.frame = frame;

        return subView.frame;
    }

    return subView.frame;
}
```

I tried the following properties either in viewDidLoad or viewWillLayoutSubviews but it didn't work.

```
[self.detailView setNeedsLayout];
[self.detailView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Move the method call for patchSubViewPadding: out of viewDidAppear and to the bottom of viewDidLoad.

Comment: patchSubViewPadding call is not in viewWillAppear. I also tried patchSubViewPadding in viewDidLoad but nothing has changed. Why do I have to click to an another tab and then click the first tab to see the subview fitted? it is weird..

Comment: try moving [CommonUtilities patchSubViewPadding:self.detailView subView:self.customViewController.view padding:0]; to under [self.detailView addSubview:self.customViewController.view]; in viewDidLoad